# Recognize notifications from particular handheld app on wear device

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a special behaviour to a notification form particular handheld app on wearable device.

What I’m trying to achieve is that notification from a handheld, that is connected to a wearable going to launch my custom application (on wear device), without a notification on wear itself. The thing is, that is has to be a notification (from phone) and it is going to come from particular app (from phone app).

Is that possible, or maybe you have any better ideas to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Send a message from Handheld to Wear using `MessageApi` method [Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html#sendMessage%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20byte[]%29) from any activity or service in Handheld  (to intimate the Wear device to start an activity or service)

   ```
   Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, nodeId, SOME_UNIQUE_MESSAGE_PATH, MY_MESSAGE);
   ```
2. Receive the message by overriding the [onMessageReceived](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onMessageReceived%28com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent%29) function in the `WearableListenerService` class in the Wear device

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

   if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(SOME_UNIQUE_MESSAGE_PATH)) {
     final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
     Log.v(TAG, "From Phone - message path : " + messageEvent.getPath());
     Log.v(TAG, "From Phone - message : " + message);
     if(message == MY_MESSAGE){
         //call your activity or service here
   }
   }
   else {
     super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Start the required `Activity` or `Service` in the Wear device from the [onMessageReceived](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onMessageReceived%28com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent%29) function